# Аутентификация в Samba по LDAP

Tags: аутентификация, samba, ldap

Необходимо дать возможность пользователям доступаться к общим дискам на удаленном сервере, используя информацию LDAP, то есть нужно, чтобы Samba обращалась к LDAP серверу и получала у проводила аутентификацию на основе его данных. Как это вообще сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках Samba нужно установить следующее

```
passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://<<your-hostname>ldap suffix =ldap admin dn
```

и выполнить

```
smbpasswd -w <ldap-secret>
```